# The set $Ham(M,\omega)$ of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms is a subgroup of the set of symplectic diffeomorphisms $Symp(M\omega)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

The set $Ham(M,\omega)$  of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms is a subgroup of the set of symplectic diffeomorphisms $Symp(M\omega)$ is proven in the following lectures notes https://jumpshare.com/s/tkHDIaSse4wwcxlG3mW1 (proof of proposition 3.42 -pag 110 (=pag 120 of the pdf))

But I have no idea what is going on in some computations:
[image]
[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

**What is going in the two highlighted statements?**

1. In the first one how do we get a sum? The derivative of a composition should be by the chain rule   $\frac{d}{dt}(\varphi_F^t\circ\varphi_G^t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\varphi_F^t)|_{\varphi_G^t}\frac{d}{dt}(\varphi_G^t)$. I don't see how they I getting a + there and why are they getting those terms
2. In the second one, how does 3.33 imply that the flow of $G^t$ is $(\varphi_F^t)^{-1}$? and how is this showing that $\varphi^{-1}\in Ham(M,\omega)$?

edit:

[image]

Comment: The first is not a chain rule application. Think carefully about the chain rule. This is a standard computation that appears in every differential geometry/topology book and that has appeared several times on this site. Convert it to a valid chain rule application by composing $\phi^t_F\circ\phi^s_G$ with $t\mapsto (s,t)=(t,t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TedShifrin pointed out the way to go. Let me write it out.

Consider formally the map $(r, s)\to \phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s$. Then by the definition of flow and the chain rule,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) &= X_{F^r}\circ \phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s,\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) &= D\phi_F^r X_{G^s}\circ \phi_G^s \quad \text{chain rule here for }\phi_F^r\circ.
\end{align*}
Now consider the map $t\to (r, s)=(t, t)$, then another chain rule for this change of variables gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} (\phi_F^t\circ \phi_G^t) &= \frac{dr}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Big|_{r=t,s=t} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) + \frac{ds}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Big|_{r=t,s=t} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s)\\
&= X_{F^t}\circ \phi_F^t\circ \phi_G^t + D\phi_F^t X_{G^t}\circ \phi_G^t.
\end{align*}

Now the second question mainly follows from the two lines after (3.3). So for the particular choice of
$$
G^t = -F^t\circ \phi_F^t,
$$
the function
$$
F^t + G^t\circ (\phi_F^t)^{-1} = F^t - F^t = 0.
$$
Its associated flow is hence the identity, $Id$, but it is also $\phi_F^t\circ \phi_G^t$. So for this particular $G^t$, we have
$$
\phi_F^t\circ \phi_G^t=Id.
$$
So $(\phi_F^t)^{-1} = \phi_G^t\in \text{Ham}(M, \omega)$, since it is generated by a function $G^t$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I still don't why  this isn't a chain rule application as I did. What is wrong with $\frac{d}{dt}(\varphi_F^t\circ\varphi_G^t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\varphi_F^t)|_{\varphi_G^t}\frac{d}{dt}(\varphi_G^t)$?

Comment: First of all I need to clarify the notation because this is not making any sense to me. Look at definition 4.1.2 that I pasted at the end (not from the same lecture notes) which uses the definition and notation I am used to. I am having trouble understanding the notation $\varphi_F^t$. Why do we need as in the proof to choose a function F to define the isotopy   $\varphi_F^t$ ?. According to 4.1.2 the isotopy is $\phi$ and fixing t, $\phi_t(x)$ is the diffeomorphism, without needing to choose any other function to define it.

Comment: @darkside Let's take a simple example. $\varphi^t_F(x)=e^{tx}$, $\varphi^t_G(x) = tx$. Then the LHS is $2tx e^{t^2x}$ and the RHS is $(y e^{ty})(y=tx) \cdot x = tx^2 e^{t^2x}$.

Comment: @rosecabbage the LHS would be $\frac{d}{dt}(2txe^{t^2x})$ but I see it is still different from the RHS. Ok I guess my chain rule application is wrong. But I am not convinced of why can't I use it without doing all that in the answer.  On another hand, Isn't $\varphi_F^t(x)$ a function of x only, because t is fixed? So d/dt(...) =0? unless x depends on t, but again t is fixed

Comment: You may have to review your ODE theory, adapted to manifolds. $\phi_F^t$ is the flow generated by $X_{F^t}$, so $\phi_F^t(x)$ is the integral curve of the (time-dependent) vector field. Concretely, $\frac{d}{dt}\phi_F^t(x) = X_{F^t}(\phi_F^t(x))=(X_{F^t}\circ \phi_F^t)(x)$, and this is the defining equation of $\phi_F^t$.

Comment: Yeah I agree on that, but what are and why do we need $F$ and $F^t$ in the notation? Looking at the wikipedia page of integral curve there is no F just a curve $\alpha$ and a vector field $X$ . So following that I would write $d/dt(\phi^t(x))=X(\phi(t)) $ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20integral%20curve,equation%20or%20system%20of%20equations.....

Comment: In $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) = X_{F^r}\circ \phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s$ why does applying the chain rule (instead of the flow definition as you did) yield 0? :
$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) = (D\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s)\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\phi_G^s=0$, because  $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\phi_G^s=0$, since $\phi_G^s$ does not depend on r

Comment: $X_{F^t}$ is the Hamiltonian vector field associated to $F^t$. (Here $F^t$ is even time-dependent, so the $t$ superscript.) For the second comment, yes, $\phi_G^s$ does not depend on $r$, so you are just differentiating the first part.

Comment: OK but we can't get different anwers for the same expression you get $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) = X_{F^r}\circ \phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s $ using the definition of flow, I get $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\phi_F^r\circ \phi_G^s) =0$ using the chain rule. We should be getting the same result. What is going on?

Comment: There is no chain rule for $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ since $\phi_F^r$ is outside, so not going through a composition function. On the other hand, $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$ needs chain rule, since $\phi_F^s$ is inside, so it went through a composition function. It also helps to pay attention to the final result. It should be a vector field on the manifold. So some of your ways won't make sense to produce that kind of result, so can't be right.